# Laravel use yield for separated layouts on different folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

in `resources` folder and `layouts/backend/` and i have `main.blade.php` file as master template and `partials` folder which that have some files such as `sidebar`, `footer` and etc, for example:

/layouts/backend/main.blade.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
           <!-- Footer -->
           @yield('partials.footer')
           <!-- /footer -->
    </body>
</html>
```

/layouts/backend/partials/footer.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.backend')

@section('footer')
    <div class="footer text-muted">Hello</div>
@endsection
```

after save and refreshing page i don't have `footer` on page

Comment: `@yield('partials.footer')` != `@section('footer')`. It seems that you wanted to `@include('partials.footer')`. Then, the `partials/footer` would `@yield('footer')` (probably). Right? Do you know what `@yield` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade), the section about Blade is really good.

I think there are a few logical issues here. If you have a footer that you want to include in your backend/master template, then there's no need to extend the layout in your footer, simply include it in your master template. Here's an example:

**layouts/backend/main.blade.php:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Laravel</title>
</head>
<body>
    @yield('main')

    <!-- Footer -->
    @include('layouts.backend.partials.footer')
    <!-- /footer -->
</body>
</html>
```

**layouts/backend/partials/footer.blade.php:**

```
<div class="footer text-muted">Hello</div>
```

Also, you might want to review your folder organisation, maybe you can go with something similar

```
views/layouts/backend.blade.php  
views/layouts/frontend.blade.php  
views/layouts/backend/footer.blade.php  
views/layouts/backend/header.blade.php
```

This is just an idea, of course you can do the folder organisation as you prefer.